# MVC DbSet,base not solving

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, radix, dbset

[image: Visual Studio Errors]

How can I solve the problem in the picture?

Comment: You are missing braces in the constructor, your first error message tells you that.

Comment: Also, please post code, not images of code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing braces in the constructor, your first error message tells you that. Change it to:

```
public UniContext() : base("UniContext") { }
```

Secondly it looks like all of your model classes are scoped to be internal to the project but you are trying to make the context public. So you are trying to expose objects that are internal. Change the context to be `internal` or `private` or make the models `public.